# Distribution of $XY$ for dependent binomials

Tags: probability, random-variables

An urn is filled with 10 balls, by placing them from a large bag containing white, black, and red balls with equal distribution.   If $X$ is the number of white and $Y$ is the number of black balls placed in the urn, find the distribution of $XY$.

---

The support is contained in all values of $k$ such that $0\le k\le 25$.  I could do a brute-force enumeration, but this seems inelegant.  I know that each of $X$ and $Y$ are binomial distributions, but I'm not sure that's very helpful given the way that they are combined here.

It seems that we need to find how many factors $k$ has, and then we could say that for each ordered factorization $k=ab$ we have $P(X=a,Y=b) = P(X=a|Y=b)P(Y=b)$ which is
$$ \binom{10-b}{a} (1/3)^a(2/3)^{10-b-a} \cdot \binom {10}{b}(1/3)^b(2/3)^{10-b} $$
Still, this approach would then require you to sum over all factorizations of $k$ which I'm not sure how to do for a general $k$.

Comment: Have you tried a simulation? Doesn't look pretty to me